# Using dplyr to group_by and conditionally mutate a dataframe by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'd like to use dplyr functions to group_by and conditionally mutate a df. Given this sample data:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   1   0.25
1   1   2   0
1   2   1   0.5
1   2   2   0
1   3   1   0.75
1   3   2   0.25
2   1   1   0
2   1   2   0.5
2   2   1   0
2   2   2   0
2   3   1   0
2   3   2   0
3   1   1   0.5
3   1   2   0
3   2   1   0.25
3   2   2   1
3   3   1   0
3   3   2   0.75
```

I want to use new column E to categorize A by whether B == 1, C == 2, and D > 0. For each unique value of A for which all of these conditions hold true, then E = 1, else E = 0. So, the output should look like this:

```
A   B   C   D    E
1   1   1   0.25 0
1   1   2   0    0
1   2   1   0.5  0
1   2   2   0    0
1   3   1   0.75 0
1   3   2   0.25 0
2   1   1   0    1
2   1   2   0.5  1
2   2   1   0    1
2   2   2   0    1
2   3   1   0    1
2   3   2   0    1
3   1   1   0.5  0
3   1   2   0    0
3   2   1   0.25 0
3   2   2   1    0
3   3   1   0    0
3   3   2   0.75 0
```

I initially tried this code but the conditionals don't seem to be working right:

```
 foo$E <- foo %>% 
    group_by(A) %>% 
    mutate(E = {if (B == 1 & C == 2 & D > 0) 1 else 0})
```

Any insights appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `foo = foo %>% mutate(E = ifelse(B == 1 & C == 2 & D > 0, 1, 0))`. Grouping by `A` makes no difference in this case. Also, only one row satisfies the listed conditions.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this doesn't actually produce the output I'm looking for. I think grouping by A is necessary because if the conditions for B, C, and D all hold true, then I want that instance of A to all get the same value of E. You're correct that only one row satisfies the listed conditions, when A = 2. So that means that when A = 1, E = 0; when A = 2, E = 1; when A = 3, E = 0.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you wanted: `foo = foo %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(E = if(any(B == 1 & C == 2 & D > 0)) 1 else 0)`

Comment: Great, this did the trick - thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @eipi10 You should post that as an answer

Comment: @MarijnStevering, I think this is probably a duplicate. The closest I could find is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34131188/496488), but I'll wait and see if anyone can find something more canonical.

Answer (score 8):

@eipi10 's answer works. However, I think you should use `case_when` instead of `ifelse`. It is vectorised and will be much faster on larger datasets.

```
foo %>% group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(E = case_when(any(B == 1 & C == 2 & D > 0) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))
```

Comment: The `ifelse` version isn't what the OP was looking for. I tested the `if` and `case_when` versions with a 5.8 million row data frame with 1000 `A` groups and the `if` version is slightly faster (0.82 seconds vs. 0.94 seconds for `case_when` on my machine).

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for testing this. Have you done the same test with ifelse as well?

Comment: I haven't tested the `ifelse` version, but `ifelse` is notoriously slow.

Comment: That's why I started using `case_when` instead. Now I learned from your experiment that `if` ... `else` is faster, which comes as somewhat of a surprise, given that it seems the more basic implementation of something pretty much the same as `ifelse`. Any particular reason why anybody would ever want to use `ifelse` then?

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized.

Comment: Well, my edit was rejected, so I use comments, there's a typo, @JanLauGe it should be mutate(E = case_when(any(B == 1 & C == 2 & D > 0) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)). Tx for the post it helped me.

Comment: You are right @Ploulack, thanks for your edit suggestion!
I've amended my answer accordingly