# group_by but only conduct piped operations on one of the groups?

Tags: r

is there a way to use dplyr group_by but only act on a subset of the group variable?

For example I want something like the following line where I am creating a var that only reports values for group==yes:

```
df%>%group_by(group=='yes')%>%mutate(min=min(value))
```

and when group=='no', `min` would be NA. I know I could filter beforehand but I still want to keep group=='no'

```
  value group want
1   1.2   yes  1.2
2   1.7   yes  1.2
3   1.0    no   NA
4   2.0    no   NA
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dplyr to group\_by and conditionally mutate a dataframe by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980374/using-dplyr-to-group-by-and-conditionally-mutate-a-dataframe-by-group)

Comment: I would say for the most part yes, but there doesn't appear to be an accepted answer in that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use a `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%          
      mutate(Min = case_when(group == 'yes' ~
                     min(value[group == 'yes'])))
```

EDIT: Based on comments from @IceCreamToucan (if we leave the `TRUE ~ NA_real_`, it would automatically fill the rest with `NA` by default)

or convert the other values to `NA` with

```
df %>% 
    mutate(Min = min(value[group == 'yes']) * NA^(group != 'yes'))
```

---

A reproducible e.g.

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(Min = case_when(am ==1 ~ min(cyl[am == 1]), TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

or without a `case_when`

```
mtcars %>% 
       mutate(Min = min(cyl[am == 1]) * NA^(am != 1))
```

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks for reminding me about that.

Answer (score 1):

We can `filter` with `group == 'yes'`, get the `min` and then do a `right_join` with the original data to get the `'no'` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(group == "yes") %>% 
  mutate(min = min(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  
  right_join(df)

#  value group min
#1   1.2   yes 1.2
#2   1.7   yes 1.2
#3   1.0    no  NA
#4   2.0    no  NA
```

In base R, that can be done with `subset` and `merge`

```
merge(df, transform(subset(df, group == 'yes'), min = min(value)), all.x = TRUE)
```