# Create column for mean of another column, filtered after a dummy variable

Tags: r, mean, dummy-variable

My table looks (simplified) like this:

```
| countrycode | year | dummy | Value

| "AUS" | 2008 | 1 | -3

| "AUS" | 2009 | 0 | -2

| "BEL" | 2008 | 0 | -5

| "BEL" | 2009 | 1 | -1

| "BEL" | 2010 | 1 | -2

| "BEL" | 2011 | 1 | -1

| "CAN" | 2008 | 0 | -2

| "CAN" | 2009 | 0 | -5

| "CAN" | 2010 | 1 | 2

| "CAN" | 2011 | 0 | -4
```

And I would like to get the Mean of the Values grouped by countrycode, like that:

```
| countrycode | year | dummy | Value | Mean

| "AUS" | 2008 | 1 | -3 | -3

| "AUS" | 2009 | 0 | -2 | -3

| "BEL" | 2008 | 0 | -5 | -1,333

| "BEL" | 2009 | 1 | -1 | -1,333

| "BEL" | 2010 | 1 | -2 | -1,333

| "BEL" | 2011 | 1 | -1 | -1,333

| "CAN" | 2008 | 1 | -2 | -0,5

| "CAN" | 2009 | 0 | -5 | -0,5

| "CAN" | 2010 | 1 | 1 | -0,5

| "CAN" | 2011 | 0 | -4 | -0,5
```

My question is how can I create a new column for mean from another column that is filtered after a dummy variable?

Comment: Please provide your data with `dput()`, because it makes easier to reproduce an example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dplyr to group\_by and conditionally mutate a dataframe by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980374/using-dplyr-to-group-by-and-conditionally-mutate-a-dataframe-by-group)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for. After grouping by `countrycode`, you can use `mutate` to create your new column. For each group, you can get the mean `Value` where `dummy` is 1. By using `mutate` you will have this added to all rows in the group, even if `dummy` is 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(countrycode) %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(Value[dummy == 1]))
```

**Output**

```
   countrycode  year dummy Value  mean
   <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1 AUS          2008     1    -3 -3   
 2 AUS          2009     0    -2 -3   
 3 BEL          2008     0    -5 -1.33
 4 BEL          2009     1    -1 -1.33
 5 BEL          2010     1    -2 -1.33
 6 BEL          2011     1    -1 -1.33
 7 CAN          2008     1    -2 -0.5 
 8 CAN          2009     0    -5 -0.5 
 9 CAN          2010     1     1 -0.5 
10 CAN          2011     0    -4 -0.5
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(countrycode = c("AUS", "AUS", "BEL", "BEL", "BEL", 
"BEL", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN", "CAN"), year = c(2008L, 2009L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L), dummy = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Value = c(-3L, -2L, -5L, 
-1L, -2L, -1L, -2L, -5L, 1L, -4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

your_data_frame %>% 
  filter(dummy == 1) %>%
  group_by(countrycode) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: How do I add that I only want to use it on values on the same row with dummy=1?

Comment: Updated my answer, using `filter`

Comment: doing this, I'll get the mean of all values together with dummy ==1, but I want for every country an unique value (being the mean of their values). Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: Ok, `mutate` keeps the data dimensions, to summarise you can use `summarize`/`summarise` instead

Comment: With summarize I'll still get only one value (mean of all variables with dummy==1).

Comment: You want the mean of each country code, only for dummy = 1, correct?