# Using dplyr::group_by to run a set of functions depending on the value of the grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Using dplyr's grouping function in R, I should like to execute a set of functions, depending on the value of the grouping variable. Specifically, I have two conditions, stim.type and block.type. For each level of stim.type I should like to execute one set of functions if block.type is p and another set of functions if block.type is m. I then want to create a new column in my tibble ("rating"), based on the output of these sets of functions (e.g. "yes", "no", "no", "no", "yes", etc.). Naturally, the output should be different each time (i.e. for each level of stim.type and for each level of block.type), given that random sampling is involved here. Put simply, later on I want to be able to select individual rows from the tibble based on the output for the new rating column (yes vs no) - the selection should be based on random sampling. I am providing an example below:

```
set.seed(0)
library(tidyverse)

# Create sample tibble
df <- dplyr::tibble(
stim.type = c(rep("a",35),rep("b",35), rep("c",35),rep("d",35)),
block.type = rep(c(rep("m",15),rep("p",20)),4)
)

# Current script
df <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(stim.type, block.type) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(rating = if (block.type=="p"){
    sample(c(rep("yes",3),rep("no",17)), 20) # execute this if block.type is p
  } else if (block.type=="m") { sample(c(rep("yes",3),rep("no",12)), 15) # execute this if block.type is m
  })
```

My current script generates an error message, however:

```
"Caused by error in `if (block.type == "p") ...`:
! the condition has length > 1".
```

Any pointers as to how to resolve this would be much appreciated. I have already consulted various related answers on this, but none showed how to do this with conditional functions in reference to the value of the grouping variable (e.g.: [Using dplyr to group_by and conditionally mutate a dataframe by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42980374/using-dplyr-to-group-by-and-conditionally-mutate-a-dataframe-by-group)).

Comment: Hi Tiberius! With `sample(c(rep("yes",3),rep("no",17)), 20)`, are you just wanting to sample from a Bernoulli distribution (a.k.a. weighted coin flip distribution?)

Comment: Also, you say you want it grouped by stim type, but stim type seems irrelevant to the code you are running, as the coin flips don't change according to stim type. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mark it looks like the weightings for the coin flip are different for the different groups?

Comment: You are trying to asssign vector (result of sample() call) to cell. If you do really need such an assignment you can cast it to list() prior the assignment, otherwise you need to revise your code and specify what is your desired result.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen they're different for different block types, but not different stim types from what I can see

Comment: @Mark you're right, sorry. Let's see what Tiberius replies.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have updated my question for clarification. I need to randomly sample for each of the four levels in stim.type, but as a function of block.type.

Comment: thanks for that Tiberius. I note that you didn't answer my question, and your edits don't answer it either. Would you be willing to do that now?

Comment: @Mark. Thank you, in principle the default distribution underlying the sample function in R should be sufficient for my purposes, at least from what I know. There are two factors (stim.type and block.type) in my example, with a total of 4x2=8 individual conditions. In essence, I need to separately sample for each of these 8 different conditions. However, the two conditions of block.type have a different number of cells. Hence, slightly adjusted functions need to do the sampling for each level of block type. I hope this made it a bit clearer.

Comment: thanks for explaining that! So after you explaining that, I can say fairly conclusively that you don't need to group by stim.type, it's useless in the context. The number of rows in each stim.type group isn't important if you are just sampling from a distribution once for each row, which is what you ought to be doing (simpler + easier + easier to read/debug!)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr::cur_group()` which returns a one-row tibble of all grouping variables with the current group shown in the first row. To access the current `block.type` group we can use  `$` as in `cur_group()$block.typ`:

```r
# Current script
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(stim.type, block.type) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(rating = if (cur_group()$block.type=="p") {
    sample(c(rep("yes",3),rep("no",17)), 20) # execute this if block.type is p
  } else if (cur_group()$block.type=="m") {
    sample(c(rep("yes",3),rep("no",12)), 15) # execute this if block.type is m
  })

#> # A tibble: 140 × 3
#> # Groups:   stim.type, block.type [8]
#>    stim.type block.type rating
#>    <chr>     <chr>      <chr> 
#>  1 a         m          no    
#>  2 a         m          no    
#>  3 a         m          no    
#>  4 a         m          no    
#>  5 a         m          yes   
#>  6 a         m          yes   
#>  7 a         m          no    
#>  8 a         m          yes   
#>  9 a         m          no    
#> 10 a         m          no    
#> # ℹ 130 more rows
```

Data from OP

```r
set.seed(0)
library(tidyverse)

# Create sample tibble
df <- dplyr::tibble(
  stim.type = c(rep("a",35),rep("b",35), rep("c",35),rep("d",35)),
  block.type = rep(c(rep("m",15),rep("p",20)),4)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `dplyr::cur_group()`.
To make this generalisable to any number of options I used `case_when()` instead of `if_else()` but this requires the ouputs of equal length.  I chose to do this with helper columns (`m_flip` and `p_flip`) but there are other ways:

```
df |> mutate(m_flip = sample(c(rep("yes",3),rep("no",17)), n(), replace = TRUE),
         p_flip = sample(c(rep("yes",3),rep("no",12)), n(), replace = TRUE)) |>
  mutate(flip = case_when(cur_group()$block.type == "m" ~ m_flip,
                          cur_group()$block.type == "p" ~ p_flip),
             .by = block.type) |>
  select(-c(m_flip, p_flip))

# A tibble: 140 × 3
   stim.type block.type flip 
   <chr>     <chr>      <chr>
 1 a         m          no   
 2 a         m          no   
 3 a         m          yes  
 4 a         m          no   
 5 a         m          no   
 6 a         m          no   
 7 a         m          no   
 8 a         m          no   
 9 a         m          yes  
10 a         m          no   
# … with 130 more rows
```

Comment: Paul you could also have used `case_match()` in this case (pun intended), as it's perfect for this scenario. Also don't forget to add a seed, so your results are reproducible :-)